# printf freezes the program

Tags: printf, deadlock, vxworks

I am working on a project with VxWorks which involves many tasks that are running in parallel, every task run in infinite loop **while(1)**,
Also, every task uses "**printf**" function at some points and prints to the console some variables.

When I run the program whilst TeraTerm is openned and I can see the printings, everything works fine. The problem appears sometimes when TeraTerm is closed and there is no console for output printings, then suddenly the application could be frozen until I open TeraTerm and click on **Enter**  which releases the freezing.

It's hard to catch when it will happen but last time I caught it I saw this sequence:

[image]

**tGRS_systemStates is the frozen task.**

I think that the key for this problem is that something with the output buffer happens at it does not have any output for the printings and then I stuck with the semTake operation, kind of a deadlock I would say.
Does someone have any hint of where should I research? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproductible example to help?

Comment: Disable serial flow control of Tera Term.

Comment: The problem occurs when Tera Term is off, it's not Tera Term's problem.

Answer (score 0):

printf() is sending the character to the output serial interface through a buffer. The buffer is set to 512 (hardcoded in the call to ttyDevCreate()).
That buffer is emptied by the TX interrupts. Every new printf() would trigger the transmission.

Use the system mode debugging and set a breakpoint to the TX interrupt handler for that serial interface. It might not be hit when you have the issue.

Set a breakpoint to the "txstartup" function of the serial driver. This would confirm that if the TX interrupt is getting enabled (and sometimes the first write of the char to sent is written into the register).